# Introducir un numero entero de tres cifras y guardar cada cifra en la lista, después ordenar sin alterar su orden relativo. Python

Tags: python

Hola estoy teniendo problemas para resolver este problema, lo realicé con una lista auxiliar pero necesito hacerlo sin ella y no sé ni cómo comenzar, alguien podría ayudarme?
utilizar ciclo for y ordenamiento burbuja.
no se puede utilizar otras funciones que no sean append y len
adjunto mi código y como debería de quedar
[image: Asi debería quedar la lista, sin utilizar una lista auxiliar.]
Esta es mi solución:

```
nums=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros a ingresar : "))
lista=[]
listaaux=[]
for k in range(nums):
    numeros=int(input("Ingrese el numero : "))
    lista.append(numeros)
for k in range(len(lista)):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[k]>lista[i]:
            lista[k],lista[i]=lista[i],lista[k]
print(lista)
for numeros in (lista):
    centena = numeros // 100
    decena = (numeros // 10) % 10
    unidad = (numeros % 10)
    listaaux.append(centena)
    listaaux.append(decena)
    listaaux.append(unidad)
print(listaaux)
```

Comment: ¿CUál es el criterio de ordenamiento que intentas implementar?

Comment: Hay que ordenar descendentemente.

Comment: QUé puedes o no puedes usar? No pongas a la gente a adivinar el enunciado del problema :) Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir la información que haga falta

Comment: Afortunadamente tuve profesores inteligentes capaces de pensar problemas donde ocupar **todo** lo aprendido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es bien simple: básicamente es ordenar la lista, para lo cual puedes usar cualquier método disponible, como el *sort de burbujas*, el más básico de todo.

La única dificultad es que debes trabajar con tripletas completa usando *rebanada de listas*, como en `lista[i:i+3]`, que extrae una sublista de tres elementos.

Para calcular el valor de cada tripleta sin usar funciones, usamos un `for k in range(n):`, con lo cual computamos sublistas de cualquier largo, cambiando `n`, el tamaño de sublista.

Propongo esta solución genérica, válida para cualquier `n`.

```
lista=[1,2,3,7,4,5,0,7,8,3,6,3,7,4,6,7,2,6]
n = 3

for i in range(0, len(lista), n):
    for j in range(i+n, len(lista), n):
        #  Calcular valor decimal del número.
        a, b = 0, 0
        for k in range(n):
            a = a * 10 + lista[i+k]
            b = b * 10 + lista[j+k]
        if a < b:
            lista[j:j+n], lista[i:i+n] = lista[i:i+n], lista[j:j+n]
```

Me salto la parte de pedir la lista, pues ahí no tienes dificultad.

produce:

```
[7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 3, 6, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 7, 8]


Process finished with exit code 0
```